# HTML5 offline browser cacheing pages it shouldn't

Tags: html, browser-cache, offline

I am testing HTML5's offline capabilities, and the cache seems to be a bit overactive. My cache.appcache file is as follows:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
CACHE:
#v1.4
js/js.js

NETWORK:
network2.html

FALLBACK:
/ offline.html
```

Basically I want to only display network2.html when the web is available - otherwise it should fall back to offline.html.

However, if I have accessed network2.html with the web connection live it keeps displaying it when there is no connection - surely it should fall back to offline.html? I thought only pages referenced in the CACHE section should be cached in the first place anyway?

I have tried in multiple browsers, clearing the browser data, refreshing multiple times etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it - it turns out that any file whose html tag references the manifest will be cached itself, *whether or not that file is mentioned in the CACHE section*. This even overrides if it is referenced in the NETWORK section.

Thanks to robertc on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263266/cache-manifest-while-offline-replace-all-pages-with-a-single-you-are-offline?rq=1) answer which gave me the tip.

In short, you only need to have *one* reference to the manifest, usually in your 'default' view, *not* all files that may be referenced by the manifest itself. Not very clear in the HTML5 docs.